# Bean value update problem in jsf 1.1

Tags: jsf

I have One Jsf form that contains 2 Beans. First Bean scope: Session. Second Bean scope:  request.

When some values are added via First Bean to second Bean, the updated value is not displayed in the form. I don't know how to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you fired a *redirect* which caused the request scoped bean being renewed, or the values are updated at the *wrong* moment which caused them being overridden later in the JSF lifecycle.

To fix the first, ensure that you aren't including `<redirect/>` in navigation case nor did call `ExternalContext#redirect()` in bean action method. To fix the second, well, run a debugger. [This article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) may also help a lot in understanding what's going on under the JSF hoods.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC has shown what are the possible reasons for this problem.

In case it is the redirection one, removing the redirect solves the problem, but adds another - the user is asked to resubmit the form if he refreshes the page.

A preferred way to achieve such transitions from one page to another is to use a conversation. [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html) provides a special conversation scope to solve this and many more problems.